# Найти индекс элемента list по его значению

Tags: c#, массивы

Собственно вопрос в названии темы. Есть коллекция:

```
  List<int> styleID = new List<int>();
```

В неё добавлено несколько ID (`221432`, `445566`, `998877` и т.д.). Как узнать индекс элемента со значением `998877`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Простой способ - вызов метода `IndexOf()`:

```
var indexOfIntegerValue = styleID.IndexOf(998877);
```

В переменную `indexOfIntegerValue` получите значение, соответствующее индексу числа 998877 в указанной коллекции.
В случае, если Ваша коллекция не содержит такого числа (998877), этот метод вернёт значение `-1`.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать `Linq`, лямбда выражение и метод `FindIndex`:

```
list<int> styleID = new List<int>(); 
int index = styleID.FindIndex(x => x == 998877);
```

[msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/x1xzf2ca(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: `FindIndex` это не `Linq` ;)

Answer (score 0):

У коллекции типа List есть метод `IndexOf(T)`

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<int> tokamak = new List<int> { 1, 1, 3, 1, 7 };
        var elementIndexCount = tokamak
                               .Select((e, i) => new { e, i })
                               .GroupBy(x => x.e, (k, e) => new
                               {
                                   Element = k,
                                   Index = e.Select(z => z.i).ToList(),
                                   Count = e.Count()
                               })
                             .ToList();
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]